# Responsive web design breakpoint in inches?

Tags: css, responsive-design

Because of increasing pixel density, especially in handheld/mobile devices but in laptops as well, does it make sense to define breakpoints for responsive CSS using inches?

For example, if I have an existing mobile-first layout by default and want to separately specify styles for a 15.6 inch laptop and larger displays, does it make sense to use *@media (min-width: 13in)*? (15.6in diagonal screen = 13in wide). Will this cause any problems, is it well supported? Intuitively it makes more sense to define overall layout based on the absolute size of the screen than on the number of pixels.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it turns out that the CSS specification defines inches and millimeters [based on pixels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units#Numbers_lengths_and_percentages). In CSS, 1in = 2.54cm = 96px, so this will display as 1 physical inch only on screens with 96 ppi, but for example, the iPhone X has 463 ppi and if you specify something in CSS to be width=1in; the physical screen display will be only 0.2 inches wide!